# Using R for dice probabilities

Tags: r, probability, dice

Using R, what function(s) would I use to obtain the following probabilities?

- Roll at least one 1 when rolling 2 six-sided dice (2d6) = 11/36
- Roll at least one 1 when rolling 3 six-sided dice (3d6) = 91/216
- Roll at least one 1 when rolling 1d4, 1d6, 1d8, and 1d8 = 801/1536

First I hope my answers above are correct!  I did these pretty much manually.

I think I need to use binomial distributions and/or probability-generating functions, but not sure if I'm over-complicating things.  I've tried using R's *binom() functions but can't seem to arrive at the answers I need.

Comment: The last answer of $654/1536$ is too low. For a brute force (but illuminating) calculation, try `dice <- expand.grid(1:4, 1:6, 1:8, 1:8);
dim(subset(dice, subset=(Var1==1 | Var2==1 | Var3==1 | Var4==1)))[1]` and inspect the contents of `dice` afterwards: it shows all $1536$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Made the edit, `801 / 1536` is the correct probability for the last question.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that last one.  My main goal here is to arrive at these probabilities without having to load a potentially very large table into memory.  Also I want to use standard statistical methods instead of a package that abstracts it all for you, e.g. the 'dice' package.  But I do thank @djhurio for providing that info.

Comment: You can do `dice$containsOne <- apply(dice, 1, function(roll) 1 %in% roll)`, then use dplyr %>% pipe or data.table := directly into a summarize. You could save memory by making each row-index a unique string summarizing the rolls e.g. "3287" or "3:2:8:7". (for dice with <- 10 sides, you could directly use a decimal integer like 3287 as row-index, save more memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**

There is a package `dice` that could help you. I got the same probabilities for the first two examples, but not for the last one. See the example code:

```
require(dice)

# Roll at least one 1 when rolling 2 six-sided dice (2d6) = 11/36
getEventProb(nrolls = 2, ndicePerRoll = 1, nsidesPerDie = 6,
             eventList = list(1))
11/36

# Roll at least one 1 when rolling 3 six-sided dice (3d6) = 91/216
getEventProb(nrolls = 3, ndicePerRoll = 1, nsidesPerDie = 6,
             eventList = list(1))
91/216

# Roll at least one 1 when rolling 1d4, 1d6, 1d8, and 1d8 = 654/1536
p1 <- getEventProb(nrolls = 1, ndicePerRoll = 1, nsidesPerDie = 4,
                   eventList = list(1))
p2 <- getEventProb(nrolls = 1, ndicePerRoll = 1, nsidesPerDie = 6,
                   eventList = list(1))
p3 <- getEventProb(nrolls = 2, ndicePerRoll = 1, nsidesPerDie = 8,
                   eventList = list(1))

p1 + p2 + p3 - p1 * p2 - p2 * p3 - p3 * p1 + p1 * p2 * p3
801/1536

### The same as
1 - (1-p1) * (1-p2) * (1-p3)
801/1536
```

**Solution 2**

This is a solution with out usage of any package. You can compute the probability to draw at least one $1$ by this formula (mentioned by @whuber):

$$ p = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{d_i} \right) $$

where $n$ is the number of dices and $d_i$ is the number of sides of dice $i$.

Then you can define a function in R with one argument `dices`, where `dices` is a vector of sides. See the example code:

```
dice.prob <- function(dices) 1 - prod(1 - 1 / dices)

dice.prob(c(6, 6))
11/36

dice.prob(c(6, 6, 6))
91/216

dice.prob(c(4, 6, 8, 8))
801/1536
```

Comment: What is the basis of your last calculation?

Comment: @whuber, it is just another way hot to calculate the probability of three independent events. Added alternative to the answer.

Comment: It looks better now, but how do you wind up with an incorrect answer?  The full formula is $1 - (1-1/4)(1-1/6)(1-1/8)(1-1/8)$ = $801/1536$.

Comment: @whuber, both solutions are equivalent. The wrong answer was taken from the question. Made a correction to the answer by deleting the wrong answer.

Comment: @djhurio thanks but I'm more interested in knowing the methods behind the scenes.  So I want to know how the dice package arrived at these answers.

Comment: @Tim The `dice` package has a [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dice/dice.pdf), and if that doesn't answer your questions you can always look at code in the package source.

Comment: @Tim, added the 2nd solution without usage of packages.

Answer (score 1):

These are arithmetically very simple problems. Therefore, it's not clear in what way you intend to use R as a calculator to solve your problems for you. Focusing on example 3 as the hardest example:
For U=d4, X=1d6, Y=1d8, and Z=1d8:

Pr(U=1 or X=1 or Y=1 or Z=1) = 1 - Pr(U!=1 and X!=1 and Y != 1 and Z!=1)

This is 1- 3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 7/8 = 801/1536

You can of course plug in `1-3/4 * 5/6 * 7/8 * 7/8`  to your terminal and obtain the probability. tada.

You could simulate:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e8
u = sample(1:4, n, replace=T)
x = sample(1:6, n, replace=T)
y = sample(1:8, n, replace=T)
z = sample(1:8, n, replace=T)

mean(u==1 | x==1 | y==1 | z==1)
```

Gives
`0.5215`

Other than that, the existence of and the need for a package to do thinking on a probability problem like this implies a lack of thought.

Answer (score 0):

```r
nothrows <- seq(6, by = 6, length.out = 200)

probsix <- 0
for(i in 1: length(nothrows)) {
  samp <- sample.int(6, nothrows[i], replace = TRUE)
  probsix[i] <- sum(samp == 6)/nothrows[i]
}
probsix
```

I would do something like this and just change the values manually as required.